# How do I get a FOR XML AUTO result to be more than 256 characters from SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

I've found various solutions to this issue but they don't seem to work. I have a query that returns a single result that has about 6 nested rows in it. The rough shape is:

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <Item />
  <Item />
  <Item />
  <Item />
</ItemGroup>
```

with each Item having about 8 elements in it. I'm using FOR XML AUTO, TYPE to produce the XML. The query has a [nested query in it to produce the inner rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522515.aspx). So far so good. However when I run the query my XML is *always* trimmed at 256 characters. The first suggestion to fix this is to change the XML data to Unlimited (or 5MB, they both should be adequate) for its max return size in *Tools, Options, Query Results, SQL Server, Results to Grid, XML Data.* Seems sensible. Didn't work.

If I output to grid I get an error about an unclosed string:

[image: unclosed literal]

My next attempt to fix was just to output the results to a file. I don't see any options for changing the amount of data (max) to return there, so I assume it's unlimited. However, dumping the result to a file resulted in the exact same problem: 1 row x 256 columns in the result text.

Can this be fixed? Is this a bug in SSMS 2014? The exact version is 12.0.2000.8. My next step will be to just send the result rows to a node.js script and manipulate the XML there instead.

**Edit**: I ran the query through node and the shaping I was doing with `FOR XML AUTO, TYPE` is clearly goofed up. The result doc was 35MB. But if I run the query without the shaping I get a 9 row result set. Still: I would not have been able to figure that out with SSMS, even when outputting directly to a file.

Comment: Did you try restarting SSMS after making the change or at least opening a new query window?

Comment: wow check  out the results (it's not an improvement, but clearly a change): http://imgur.com/1r3unTy

Comment: That normally indicates SSMS is out of memory AFAIK, or perhaps some unhandled error. I've seen that before and normally reopening SSMS fixes it.

Comment: Please post the SELECT statement... 256 Characters is the default max size for text output. You could try to set a higher value there. But as you mention "to grid" I assume that you get a grid result and try to click on the underlined XML.

Comment: Tried outputting to a file after the restart, it still got trimmed but I got more; the trim amount appears to be governed by the  max column characters in the Results to Text options. Which tops out at 8192 characters. WTF, huge QA fail by Microsoft.

Comment: @Shnugo see my latest comment; I'd rather not post the select since I'd have to sanitize it. I assure you it's much less than the max file size on a Windows machine.

Comment: @MartinSmith re: out of memory: the results of this query are not even remotely large enough to max out the memory -- I'm on a 64 bit server with 16GB of memory. Even on a 32b machine this query shouldn't max out the memory.

Comment: I deal with XML data far beyond 8192 characters... If the Xml--size is set to "unlimited" and you get the result in grid, the limit of the XML may be huge... The problem could be, that (e.g. by conversion?) the XML is cut and therefore structurally invalid

Comment: I will run the SQL query through node instead of SSMS and report back.

Comment: See my edit to the question if you're curious what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a month and I didn't get much of a resolution to this. My real solution was to not use `FOR XML AUTO, TYPE`. Not because it's broken, but because it's too easy to goof up and result in long cycles of cryptic debugging. Better to shape the XML by hand (in Node in my case) unless you really really need to understand how to shape XML in SQL. Read the comments above if you are curious why I went that way.